# Prevenir error cargar secuencia no segura en stacksnippet que utiliza librerías externas

Tags: discusión, stack-snippets

Al copiar el código en el jsfiddle que el OP incluyó en [Error primera columna en un chart de Google charts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18365/65) a stacksnippet, en Chrome, la advertencia de secuencia se muestra en la barra de direcciones de Chrome.  ¿Cómo evito que esto pase?

[image]

A continuación el código, se excluyó el código de generación de gráfico:

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        $("#tabid").html('the tab id is ' + $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href"));

    }
}

);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eef;
}
#tabs {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
/* Note that jQuery UI CSS is loaded from Google's CDN in the "Add Resources" pane to the left.  Normally this would be done in your <head> */
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
       
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
         <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hasta que estaba a punto de publicar la pregunta me percaté que un par de referencias externas incluían `http` en lugar de `https`. Me auto-respondo por si a alguien más le pasa, o a mí se me olvida, lo cual es 100% seguro XD

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        $("#tabid").html('the tab id is ' + $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href"));

    }
}

);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eef;
}
#tabs {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
/* Note that jQuery UI CSS is loaded from Google's CDN in the "Add Resources" pane to the left.  Normally this would be done in your <head> */
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
       
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
         <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
```